# Interpretation of a contour diagram

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

Below is a contour diagram below for the sales of a product as a function of the price and the amount spent for advertising. Which axis corresponds to the latter?

[image: Diagram]

If $y$ is fixed and $x$ increases, then the sales decrease. So $x$ corresponds to the price, and $y$ corresponds to the amount spent for advertising. Am I right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes I would think so. If it were flipped, then for a fixed price, as the amount of advertising increases, the sales would decrease, which intuitively doesn’t make sense. However it’s always good to note if you’re dealing with a special case, so there may be a more concrete way of going about it if there was more information presented in the problem.